# Print out method / function name where the Sphinx directive is coming from

Tags: python, pytest, python-sphinx

I created an own extension for Sphinx documentation inside pytest according to the ToDo example.
This is reading and collecting the "test_summary" from every docstring of every pytest test_function.

```
def test_sphinx():
    """
    This is the first sentence in the test_sphinx test case.

    .. test_summary:: This is the test summary one

    """
    pass
```

This is working fine.

Now I like to collect these test_summaries inside an own file.
example for now:

```
File collection_of_test_summaries:


Test_summary
This is the test summary one
```

This is working too.
But I like to print out the function name, here: "test_sphinx" for every directive, like that:

```
File collection_of_test_summaries:

test_sphinx:
Test_summary
This is the test summary one
```

According to the Sphinx ToDo example I have the document (module) name, but I'm not able to find the function name.

Sphinx ToDo example:
https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/development/tutorials/todo.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

I use

```
self.content.items[0][0].split()[-1]
```

inside the

```
run()
```

function of the

```
class MyDirective(SphinxDirective):
```

class.

This works fine.